# How can I switch languages like Windows

Tags: language-support, input-language

How can I switch languages like in Windows with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>(L or R) or in any of <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>?

I make it work to get the next languages but it didn't get back to main language without using <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> OR <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>.

Comment: Install a IM and configure it appropriately.

Comment: @khalidzuhd if you happen to use xfce4, install xfce4-xkb-plugin and add it to your panel. You can then configure the keyboard shorcuts and which languages to use.

Comment: Please *edit* your question to include your Ubuntu version, your desktop environment (Unity, KDE, etc), the input method you are using (probably Ibus), and the language(s) you plan to use.

Answer (score 3):

### Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

---

I'll assume you have [added a second (or more) keyboard layouts](https://askubuntu.com/a/259888/58950). If so, a keyboard indicator will appear on the top of your screen.

[image: keyboard indicator drop-down menu]

If you click on it, a menu will appear; go to the last option, **Keyboard layout configuration...**. You'll see the same settings window from where you added the additional layout(s):

[image: keyboard layout settings window]

<sup>Note: You would have more than one keyboard layout listed on the left-hand section.</sup>

Click on the **Options...** button on the lower right corner.

On the "Keyboard layout options" window, navigate down to **Key(s) to change layout**, click on it and select the combination of keys that better suit you.

[image: keyboard layout settings options - interchange layout key(s)]

**Note**: please keep in mind that my system is in Spanish, so the actual phrasing or words of the options, menus or applications might be somewhat different from what I've written in English. Feel free to correct (me or the post directly).