# How can I get the correct Spanish Keyboard layout?

Tags: keyboard-layout

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 and I can't seem to get the right Spanish keyboard layout. I'm used to using the Windows Spanish (International) layout with dead keys on the US apostrophe and open bracket, as well as a <kbd>ç</kbd> where the US layout has a <kbd>\</kbd>. The dead keys I'm used to are an acute accent (`´`) where <kbd>'</kbd> is, a diæresis/"umlaut" (`¨`) where the <kbd>"</kbd> is, a grave accent (`` ` ``) where the <kbd>[</kbd> is, and a circumflex (`^`) where the <kbd>{</kbd> is. I am also used to having `°` where the <kbd>`</kbd> is.

The keyboard layout that I have also does not allow me to type `@`, `#`, or any of the other characters that I am used to typing by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + (key). The previews of keyboard layouts included with Ubuntu are unhelpful and confusing to me. Can anyone help me find or construct the keyboard layout I'm looking for?

Answer (score 14):

Press the *Super* key and start typing "keyboard" (for you, it would be "teclado") and open "Keyboard layout" ("Distribución del teclado"). Alternatively, you open "System configuration" ("Configuración del sistema") and select "Keyboard layout".

[image: find keyboard layout]

There you can add another keyboard layout, by clicking on the button with a "+" symbol at the bottom left, check the layout itself by clicking on the little keyboard button, and even change some of the options for your preferred layout (button "Options..." at the bottom right). The latter would let you customize the layout.

[image: keyboard layout window]

As for typing characters in a manner similar to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+number, check this question: [How can I type ASCII characters like Alt + numpad in Windows?](https://askubuntu.com/q/88347/58950)

If you only want to know what key combinations are available in you current keyboard layout, click on the little keyboard button (highlighted in pink in the image, below) after you selected the layout.

[image: the keyboard layout]

The combinations of keys are as follow:

[image: key combinations]

Comment: Nice one. Very complete. Muy bueno te quedo ^^.