# How to write a "@" with a French Canadian Keyboard

Tags: keyboard-layout

I try to do a "@" but each times a press on <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> to get it, the Top menu of the app/windows show off (File/Edit/View/Tool...)

If a try with a English Canadian's Layout or a English USA, I got the same problem.

On Lubuntu or Xubuntu 12.10, I don't get this problem. That really seem to come from
Unity's Shortcut. I am Using Ubuntu 12.10.

Comment: I edited your question, please tell me if the structure is fine. So, the problem is that you **can** enter `@`, but it make an ugly behavior in the screen, right? When you say `Alt`, are you talking about `Alt Gr`? Because this keys are slightly different.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd>, is it?

Comment: Normally, Yes.
But each time I press on ALT, the top Menu appear on the Windows/Application (File,Edit,View...)

Comment: @Kamikazz00 In Unity, the HUD (not the menu, except in Opera and few other programs) would normally deploy if you _release_ the ALT (**not** ALT GR) key before pressing any other key.

Comment: I remove this function of the HUD because I thinked he was the problem and nothing change!

But I just found if a press on ALT GR + 2, I can now write @

Comment: @carnendil If you disable the HUD ALT focuses the menu bar and doesn't work for shortcuts.. I think this is a known bug.

Comment: @Seth Thank you, this is something I didn't know (and with 12.04 I forced myself to get used to the HUD) :)

Answer (score 1):

In Ubuntu 12.04, (right alt key)+'2' does it for me with my french canadian keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Check/change/adjust the actual combination of keys in your current layout from the **Keyboard layout** configuration. More info [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/259888/58950).

It's possible (I don't use a French Canadian layout) that you have to use <kbd>Alt gr</kbd> (left side of the space bar) instead of <kbd>Alt</kbd>.

Comment: Thanks for the Comment but the guys is stuck at exactly the same place than me, He can't do @ and #...

Comment: If I use ALT GR + 2, I can do @

Answer (score 0):

E.g. you can:

1. run `gucharmap`
2. find whatever symbol you need
3. double click it
4. click on *Copy* button in the lower right corner
5. paste the symbol wherever you want it

For a bit more convenient way:

1. press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> keys
2. release <kbd>U</kbd>
3. enter hexadecimal unicode sequence of the symbol you want while still holding <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>
4. release <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>

Unicode for @ is 0040 (so you need to type in `40` before releasing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>). You can find other unicode sequences in `gucharmap`.

You might want to tinker with *System Settings -> Region & Language -> Layouts*, you can choose desired layout there and configure it's options (*Options* button in lower right corner of the window), however, I couldn't find anything related to *@* - maybe it's layout specific.