# Problems making "at" sign with Spanish keyboard

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

Just did a clean install of Linux on an HP Pavilion that had Windows 10. 
My keyboard is set up for Spanish language, but I am having trouble making the "at" sign @ the way I am accustomed to (i.e. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd>).

Other keys seem to work fine (accents, degree symbol, umlauts, Ñ, etc)
Anyone have a solution to this problem, aside from using the unicode method? It is so many keys to press.

Comment: Have you tried [any](https://askubuntu.com/q/363976/134479) of the [very](https://askubuntu.com/q/280492/134479) [many](https://askubuntu.com/q/259879/134479) [other](https://askubuntu.com/q/867209/134479) [questions](https://askubuntu.com/q/397322/134479) here that ask almost the same thing? If so, please explain why didn't they work.

Comment: Try <AltGr> + 2