# ^ key behaves oddly in Ubuntu GNOME 16.04 LTS

Tags: keyboard, ubuntu-gnome

Typing `^<space>` outputs `^`, and `x^2` outputs `x²`. How can I disable this setting? I'd like `x^2` to output `x^2`.

Comment: In what application? Does it do this is a terminal?

Comment: Yes, this happens in Terminal, Firefox, Texmaker, the Type-to-search box, Nautilus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your keyboard layout is most likely set to `English (US, international with dead keys)`. Open Region and Language in System Settings and change the Input Source to `English (US)` or whatever matches your actual keyboard.

Comment: `English (US)` makes `^` work the way I want, but that's not a layout I'm used to. I tried all of the `Spanish (Latin America)` layouts, two lack the `^` character and the other two behave in this annoying manner :(

Comment: @Kurzd: Have you seen "[How can I get the correct Spanish Keyboard layout](http://askubuntu.com/questions/259879/how-can-i-get-the-correct-spanish-keyboard-layout)"?

Comment: `Spanish (Latin American, eliminate dead keys)` is a bit different than I am used to but the `^` key works the way I want it to. I'm going to try this layout for a few days.

Comment: Actually, `^` works a bit different than intended, but doesn't force that number superscripting. The `´`, however, appears on-screen as soon as the key is pressed, disabling any kind of accents, which is terrible. The way it worked on Windows, for `^` and `´` was  to do nothing if pressed, but output an accented letter if a letter was pressed after, and output the accent and a non-letter if a non-letter was pressed after. This is what I've been trying to accomplish.

Comment: @Kurzd: Maybe you should return to `Spanish (Latin America)` and live with pressing a space between `^` and `2`...