# 12.04 Changing the Keyboard Layout

Tags: 12.04, keyboard-layout

I want to edit my keyboard layouts, because randomly? my keyboard layout will switch from 'English (Canada)' to 'English', completely screwing up how I type, and the only way I have found to fix it is to log out out of my session and select 'English (Canada)' on the login screen.

Apparently, I think I'm supposed to have the "Keyboard Layout" application, but it is nowhere to be found, it seems like it isn't installed on my OS, and I have no idea what to install to enable it.

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu, by the way. I hope your keyboard problem gets fixed soon!

Comment: Is there reason you are using 12.04 ubuntu?

Comment: I would upgrade from 12.04 to 16.04 at least if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Go to **System Settings**, and choose *Keyboard Layout*

Just add the desired layouts, and a new icon will appear on the right top corner of the screen, along with the other notification icons, and you can switch the layout from there at any time.

In addition, please make sure the option *Use the same distribution for all the windows* is the one selected. It's much easier that way.

Comment: Thank you, I was able to find the Keyboard Layout window, but sadly it doesn't help my issue at all. Only 'French (Canada)' is listed (sorry, wrongly stated English in my question), and yet my keyboard layout still manages to switch to English sometimes.

Comment: Just add *English*, and then put *French (Canada)* on the top of the list, and make sure it's selected on the icon I told you. This way you luckily can figure out what action is making the keyboard layout to be swithed, since the icon shows the current keyboard layout.

Comment: The first part of this answer: http://askubuntu.com/a/259888/58950 has screenshots for adding the keyboard layouts. Then, configure [how to change between layouts](http://askubuntu.com/a/282906/58950).