# How to change keyboard layout to Finnish, but keep language in English?

Tags: keyboard, 13.10, keyboard-layout, language-support

I'm able to set either everything Finnish or everything English. I want to have Finnish keyboard layout, but the OS language in English. How to do this? In the previous releases I didn't have to do anything.

Comment: I use Swedish layout with English as system language, works perfect.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### How to keep the system language in English

First, go to **System Settings** → **Language Support** and in **Langage** tab, apply system wide **English**:

[image: Language Support]

In **Regional Formats** apply system wide your favorite **English**:

[image: Regional Formats]

Second, go to **System Settings** → **User Accounts** and select **English** as your language:

[image: User Accounts]

### How to change keyboard layout to Finnish

Go to **System Settings** → **Text Entry** and add **Finnish** keyboard layout:

[image: Text Entry]

See also: [Keyboard layout switches to English each time I reboot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/362973/language-problem-in-ubuntu-13-10)

Comment: I have two objections to this answer. First: Regional formats is a third aspect that is not mentioned in the question. It's likely that a Finnish user prefers regional formats that are typical for Finland rather than the US. Second: If you have set the user language from Language Support (which you do by controlling which option is on top of the list), there is no reason to also go to User Accounts.

Comment: There's still something horribly wrong, because my Qt apps are using Finnish translations even though the system language is now English and Finnish language support is not even installed. If I set LANG=en_US.UTF-8 when starting the app it's still in Finnish. It seems that the whole locale/keyboard layout system in 13.10 is a mess. Everything worked just fine under 13.04.

Comment: @user205301 That's because you have installed them in Finnish language. Try to change their language from their menus.

Comment: In my case there are no menus. Qt should switch the language based on LANG anyway. It worked before.

Comment: @user205301 Well, if you followed first step from the answer, after a system reboot, your applications should be in English if these have a translation in English. Try also `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`.

Comment: Hmm...QLocale::system() returns always fi_FI no matter what I do. I think I'll file a bug against this.

Comment: @user205301 Hmmm... What have you set for "Regional Formats" (second image from the answer)? And have you take in consideration that changes take effect next time you login?

Comment: @user205301: Ubuntu works with LANGUAGE, too, not only LANG. If you open Language Support and change the selected language to something else, and then back to what you want, it should be ok next time you log in.

Comment: It was the regional formats that caused this :) Thanks!

Comment: I didn't follow it because I didn't understand why regional formats would affect translations. And I still don't, because there's a separate system language setting. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Having installed your system in English, [add a Finnish keyboard layout](https://askubuntu.com/a/259888/58950). Then configure how to [change between layouts](https://askubuntu.com/a/282906/58950).

But if you are going to make a brand new installation of Ubuntu, there is a step in the installation process ([Nº 10 in this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/152902/58950)) where it asks you to set your keyboard layout.